# How to parse multiple string patterns in linux shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I am new to linux shell and I had a hard time thinking of the solution to this. Can somebody help how to parse multiple strings (data) in a file? For below file, I want to parse all the values next to `BIG*20021208*00001**` which are the following: `A999`, `A1000`, `1001`.

```
ST*810*0001
BIG*20021208*00001**A9
99*N1*ST*XYZ Test Corporation*9*122334455
N3*987 Freeway Dr.
N4*New York*NY*98765
N1*BT*ABC Test Company*9*122334455
N3*123 Highway Street
N4*Los Angeles*CA*12345
ITD*01*3*2**30**30*****60
FOB*PP
IT1**1*EA*200**UA*EAN
PID*F****Lamp
IT1**4*EA*50**UA*EAN
PID*F****Chair
TDS*2000
CAD*****Routing
ISS*30*CA
CTT*50
SE*19*0001
ST*810*0002
BIG*20021208*00001**A1000
N1*ST*XYZ Test Corporation*9*122334455
N3*987 Freeway Dr.
N4*New York*NY*98765
N1*BT*ABC Test Company*9*122334455
N3*123 Highway Street
N4*Los Angeles*CA*12345
ITD*01*3*2**30**30*****60
FOB*PP
IT1**1*EA*200**UA*EAN
PID*F****Lamp
IT1**4*EA*50**UA*EAN
PID*F****Chair
TDS*2000
CAD*****Routing
ISS*30*CA
CTT*50
SE*19*0002
ST*810*0003
BIG*20021208*00001**10
01N1*ST*XYZ Test Corporation*9*122334455
N3*987 Freeway Dr.
N4*New York*NY*98765
N1*BT*ABC Test Company*9*122334455
N3*123 Highway Street
N4*Los Angeles*CA*12345
ITD*01*3*2**30**30*****60
FOB*PP
IT1**1*EA*200**UA*EAN
PID*F****Lamp
IT1**4*EA*50**UA*EAN
PID*F****Chair
TDS*2000
CAD*****Routing
ISS*30*CA
CTT*50
SE*19*0003
```

Now, as you can see in the BIG segment, A999 value were separated already(no longer intact) . Then my problem now is when I get the data (e.g.A999) it will only generated this A9 and not the whole value which is A999.Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '/BIG.20021208.00001/!d;s/.*\*//' <<\DATA
    ST*810*0001
    BIG*20021208*00001**A999
    N1*ST*XYZ Test Corporation*9*122334455
    N3*987 Freeway Dr.
    N4*New York*NY*98765
    N1*BT*ABC Test Company*9*122334455
    N3*123 Highway Street
    N4*Los Angeles*CA*12345
    ITD*01*3*2**30**30*****60
    FOB*PP
    IT1**1*EA*200**UA*EAN
    PID*F****Lamp
    IT1**4*EA*50**UA*EAN
    PID*F****Chair
    TDS*2000
    CAD*****Routing
    ISS*30*CA
    CTT*50
    SE*19*0001
    ST*810*0002
    BIG*20021208*00001**A1000
    N1*ST*XYZ Test Corporation*9*122334455
    N3*987 Freeway Dr.
    N4*New York*NY*98765
    N1*BT*ABC Test Company*9*122334455
    N3*123 Highway Street
    N4*Los Angeles*CA*12345
    ITD*01*3*2**30**30*****60
    FOB*PP
    IT1**1*EA*200**UA*EAN
    PID*F****Lamp
    IT1**4*EA*50**UA*EAN
    PID*F****Chair
    TDS*2000
    CAD*****Routing
    ISS*30*CA
    CTT*50
    SE*19*0001
    ST*810*0002
    BIG*20021208*00001**A1000
    N1*ST*XYZ Test Corporation*9*122334455
    N3*987 Freeway Dr.
    N4*New York*NY*98765
    N1*BT*ABC Test Company*9*122334455
    N3*123 Highway Street
    N4*Los Angeles*CA*12345
    ITD*01*3*2**30**30*****60
    FOB*PP
    IT1**1*EA*200**UA*EAN
    PID*F****Lamp
    IT1**4*EA*50**UA*EAN
    PID*F****Chair
    TDS*2000
    CAD*****Routing
    ISS*30*CA
    CTT*50
    SE*19*0002
    ST*810*0003
    BIG*20021208*00001**1001
    N1*ST*XYZ Test Corporation*9*122334455
    N3*987 Freeway Dr.
    N4*New York*NY*98765
    N1*BT*ABC Test Company*9*122334455
    N3*123 Highway Street
    N4*Los Angeles*CA*12345
    ITD*01*3*2**30**30*****60
    FOB*PP
    IT1**1*EA*200**UA*EAN
    PID*F****Lamp
    IT1**4*EA*50**UA*EAN
    PID*F****Chair
    TDS*2000
    CAD*****Routing
    ISS*30*CA
    CTT*50
    SE*19*0003
DATA
```

That yields only these results:

```
A999
A1000
1001
```

Comment: Still it didn't work, do you think I have a wrong syntax with this line of code: NUM[$a]=`sed '/BIG.20021208.00001/!d;s/.*\*//' < /tmp/temp.file.txt` ?

Comment: @Michelle - definitely did it - the results are copy-pasted. But your thing looks correct as well. I'm not sure what the `NUM` part does though.

Comment: NUM[$a] var is for data storage

Comment: @Michelle - I've just edited it to show the exact command I used verbatim - and those are the results I received. I didn't include it before because it was so long...

Comment: It works. I will apply this to some files in my dir.

Comment: Your code works very well. Just an additional question, I had encountered that there is another value next to A999, A1000, 1001 parsed, what happen is the ones parsed were the last values and no longer these three. Any input? I think this has something to do with the code.

Comment: @Michelle - Um, i'm pretty sure i could handle that easily, but i cant get a clear picture of what you mean based on your description. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Can you please refer to the same file above as an example? What makes it different is that instead of BIG*20021208*00001**A999 it has already an additional value(e.g. BIG*20021208*00001**A999*242424). Same with my previous question, how to parse those data next to BIG*20021208*00001* which is A999 and not 242424 or the last value of the line.

Comment: @Michelle - `sed '/BIG.20021208.00001../!d;s///;s/\*.*/'`

Comment: when I run the program using above code, it says "sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unterminated `s' command"

Comment: @Michelle - my apologies. You need need one more / at the end. Like `...s/\*.*//'`

Comment: You got it right! Well done

Comment: @Michelle - Actually, this is a little better : `sed '/BIG.20021208.00001\**/!d;s///;s/\*.*//'`

Comment: Can I ask another one? What if the value next to BIG* is no longer like this - BIG.20021208.00001 instead this value for example-BIG.20022324.002312. With this, the value cannot be parse anymore since we had specified "sed '/BIG.20021208.00001" in the code.

Comment: @Michelle - In that case you have to get less specific. For instance you could start with this - `sed '/BIG.20021208.[0-9]\{1,\}\**/...'` which would handle any sequence of 1 or more digits followed by any number of `*` asterisks.

Comment: I have another question, same content with the above file but the difference is that every line has this separator (…) in which would generate another output when I parse. Unlike those file with no line separator it can really extract those specific data in the file. Can somebody help me?

Comment: @Michelle - what exactly are you asking? It might well be time for another question - but if you can provide a sample of what you mean in the comments here it's possible I could help.

Comment: :yeah, I've been asking more about parsing data but I just want to ask related question regarding parsing data. I'll just edit the same file above for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

With `GNU grep`, you can try:

```
$ grep -oP 'BIG\*20021208\*00001\*\*\K.*' file
A999
A1000
1001
```

If your `grep` version does not support `PCRE`, you can use perl instead:

```
$ perl -nle 'print $& if /BIG\*20021208\*00001\*\*\K.*/'
```

Comment: Thanks for straightening up that input, Gnouc. I was getting a little cross-eyed.

Comment: I tried above code but it didn't work out.

Comment: What is your OS and grep version?

Comment: Windows and version 4.1.2(1)